# Error from Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing when deploying Azure Web Role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I get [these](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7JK2NxH9U-BaFAwNkNBMDYtcEE/view?usp=sharing) or [these](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7JK2NxH9U-BbXliYmlCMzJEeWc/view?usp=sharing) errors everytime I deploy my service. The first time I update/deploy the application it hangs with these errors. The app runs with elevated privileges. When I reboot the instances from the portal - it starts and works fine. Does any body has explanation?

**UPDATE**
During Application_Start I read some locally stored CSV-s, make some calls to Sql Azure and Azure Tables and run Castle Windsor Installers.

Comment: Can you maybe extract some of the errors out of whatever those attachments are and post them in the question?  Also, what are your roles doing at startup?

Comment: There are only several errors which repeat a lot. During Application_Start I read some locally stored CSV-s, make some calls to Sql Azure and Azure Tables and run Castle Windsor Installers. In Visual Studio I get a message that the role recycled a number of times before in stopped. But after the restart it runs perfect. I did not extract the errors but preferred to provide the logs as is because I think whoever had encounter with such logs will be familiar with the format.